# How to change the size of FloatingActionButton?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to set a size to a `FloatingActionButton` in flutter, I wanna set `width`/`height`, I mean, make the button bigger, I was looking for a circular button, but the only one that I got was this one, so, I started to work with this, but I need it a little bigger.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use a `Container` where you can specify `width` and `height`, then use a `RawMaterialButton`, like this:

```
final myFabButton = Container(
  width: 200.0,
  height: 200.0,
  child: new RawMaterialButton(
    shape: new CircleBorder(),
    elevation: 0.0,
    child: Icon(
      Icons.favorite,
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
);
```

Comment: Please update the code, a small bracket is missed. Thanks.

Answer (score 153):

wrap your FAB with a `FittedBox` inside a `Container` or `SizedBox` and then change the width and the height of it.

> example :

```
floatingActionButton: Container(
        height: 100.0,
        width: 100.0,
        child: FittedBox(
          child: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {}),
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Comment: Even without a fitted box, the solution works fine.

Comment: Without a FittedBox, the FAB's child does not scale. Everything works fine with the FittedBox though. This is the best solution I've found, it would be nice if a proper "size" property was added though.

Comment: Whichever property you make smaller seems to define the size. If you increase the height beyond the width, it does not make an oval as you may expect; instead it moves the button up vertically along the y-axis. So if you're OK with the button at its default bottom, you need only set its width.

Answer (score 91):

#### Screenshot:

[image]

---

- **Small (40 x 40)**

  ```dart
  FloatingActionButton.small(
    onPressed: onPressed,
    child: Icon(Icons.edit),
  )
  ```
- **Regular (56 x 56)**

  ```dart
  FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: onPressed,
    child: Icon(Icons.edit),
  )
  ```
- **Large (96 x 96)**

  ```dart
  FloatingActionButton.large(
    onPressed: onPressed,
    child: Icon(Icons.edit),
  )
  ```
- **Extended**

  ```dart
  FloatingActionButton.extended(
    onPressed: onPressed,
    label: Text('Extended'),
    icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
  )
  ```
- **Custom size (A x B):**

  ```dart
  SizedBox(
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    child: FittedBox(
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        child: Icon(Icons.edit),
      ),
    ),
  )
  ```

Answer (score 56):

You do not have to reinvent the wheel, flutter team knew it will be needed.

Instead of using regular `FloatingActionButton()` use `FloatingActionButton.extended()`

example code:

```
FloatingActionButton.extended(
  onPressed: () {},
  icon: Icon(Icons.save),
  label: Text("DOWNLOAD"),
),
```

[image]

src: proandroiddev

Comment: This is not what the OP has asked in the question, kindly read the question again.

Answer (score 49):

### Update

Just using a SizedBox does not seem to scale the child inside the FAB. You need to use a FittedBox in between.

```
  floatingActionButton: SizedBox(
    height: 100.0,
    width: 100.0,
    child: FittedBox(
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Thanks [chemturion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851566/chemturion) for the comment.

Please checkout Raouf Rahiche's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52786741/272539) for more details.

---

### Old Answer

Use a [SizedBox](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html)

```
SizedBox(
  width: 200.0,
  height: 200.0,
  child: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
)
```

Comment: This works even with a notched bottom navbar and `floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked`, thanks!

Comment: One difference I notice between this approach and the Container -> FittedBox approach, is that with SizedBox parent alone, the icon in the FAB does not also scale accordingly.

Comment: @chemturion You're right. Updated the answer. Kudos!

Answer (score 14):

Most of the answers here using hardcoded values, but actually we have to apply generic solutions here, which should be constant in all the UI.

```
Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2, 
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
        child: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {}),
      ),
```

Set width and height using `MediaQuery` which will be same across the devices.

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can wrap your button with a `Transform.scale()` widget:

```
  floatingActionButton: Transform.scale(
    scale: 1.5,
    child: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {}),
  )
```

Comment: Increasing the scale factor will make button get cut from the sides.

Comment: Yes. This method does not change the center point of the button, so if the scale is too big, the sides get cut.

Comment: By contrast, `FittedBox` not only scales, it also positions the child.

Comment: another option is to use - CircleAvatar(
        radius: 42.0,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
it has radius parameter.

Comment: `Transform.scale` is a relatively expensive approach

Answer (score 5):

```
RawMaterialButton(
  elevation: 2.0,
  shape: CircleBorder(),
  fillColor: Colors.red,
  onPressed: (){},
  child: Icon(
    Icons.add,
    color: Colors.white,
    size: 20.0,
  ),
  constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(
    width: 56.0,
    height: 56.0,
  ),
)
```

BY this way .. you can add any type of button.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have implemented in one of my apps:

```
floatingActionButton: Container(
    height: 100.0,
    width: 100.0,
    child: FittedBox(
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _loadProgress,
        child: Icon(Icons.ac_unit_outlined),
        child: Text(
          'Get Joke!',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 10.0),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

FloatingActionButton has a property called mini which can be set to true.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    mini: true,
    onPressed: (){

    },
    child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow_outlined),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use extendedPadding. it works for me

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
    onPressed: () {
      // Add your onPressed code here!
    },
    extendedPadding:
        const EdgeInsets.only(left: 100, right: 100, top: 20, bottom: 20),
    label: const Text('Approve'),
    icon: const Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
    backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following option in theme.

```
floatingActionButtonTheme: const FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
  sizeConstraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `Expanded` to expand the size of the button in a row or a column:

```
    content: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(children: [
          Expanded(
              child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
```