# How to set size to FloatingActionButton - Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, mobile-application

I want to make a button bigger. the button in the card widget and it is in Align tag..

```
Align(
    alignment: Alignment(0.9, 0.9),
    heightFactor: 0.0,
    child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: null,
        child: Icon(Icons.share),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Your question is already answered in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52786652/how-to-set-size-to-floatingactionbutton

Comment: This width and height no accept in the Align tag..  how is implement?

Comment: ok. I found a solution. thankyou so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your FloatingActionButton inside a Container and manage the size of the Icon with the size element:

```
     Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 200,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: null,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.share,
              size: 80,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Align(
   alignment: Alignment(0.9, 0.9),
   heightFactor: 0.0,
   child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
               onPressed: () {},
               child: Icon(
                 Icons.share,
               ),
        ),
     ),
),
```